# Python Pandas iterrows and set_value as vectorized function

Tags: python, pandas, vectorization

I am using this function in one of my programs, and from what I have researched better performance can be achieved through vectorization.

How can I achieve the same resolution using a vectorized function rather than using the code below?

```
 for i, row in df.iterrows():
    ifor_val = something
    if <condition>:
        ifor_val = something_else
        df.set_value(i,'ifor',ifor_val)
```

Answer (score 3):

If the value depends on other values in the row, you can't avoid iterating.

```
df['ifor'] = df['some_col'].apply(lambda v: something if <condition> else something_else)
```

This puts the iteration in Pandas, so it's much cleaner (and possibly faster).

Comment: I am currently doing  for loops through tens of thousands of rows with many different conditions and setting the value based on other columns in the data frame - it seems that this way would get messy very quickly... right?

Comment: If you need multiple values from the row, use `df.apply(func, axis=1)` to call a function (`func`) with each row (one after another, in turn) as a parameter (rather than each value in a column, as my example shows).  The function you pass can be as complex as needed, it doesn't need to be a lambda.

Comment: Is there a possibility to use a vectorized function along with a regex expression to identify matches within a specified column -- then take those matches which were identified by the regex expression and set a value in a different column?

Answer (score 2):

You can use boolean indexing with loc (ix would also work but that will be deprecated so don't use it):

```
df.loc[condition, 'ifor'] = something_else
```

This will select the rows from `ifor` column that satisfy the condition and set their values to `something_else`.

Comment: as stated below by @cco 

"if the values depends on other values in the row, you can't avoid iterating" 

This is my case - I am pulling contents from different columns in the row to consolidate to column `ifor`... Is there be a way to access the `index` and `column` values for each row using your method above?